# HTML/JSX forms in React display as [object Object] instead of actual value in array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm learning React and don't have a Javascript background. The goal is to build a drop-down menu using values grabbed from an API. Rather than display the actual values, each option in my form displays [object Object] rather than the values from the API.

I can display the entire array or any values from the array anywhere except my forms. I believe the issue is a lack of understanding of how the forms (and perhaps Javascript objects) work to display.

```
class Test extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        randomName: [],
    };
}
```

Here's where I fetch from the API:

```
componentDidMount() {       
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
    .then(results => {
        return results.json();
    }).then(data => {
        let randomName = data.results.map((info => {
            return(             
                <div key={info.results}>
                    {info.name.first} {info.name.last} - {info.email}
                </div>
            )
        }))             
        this.setState({randomName: randomName});
        console.log("state", this.state.randomName);
    })
}
```

And here's where I'm attempting to create the drop-down (in the same component):

```
render() {      
    var test = this.state.randomName[0];        
    return (
    <div>               
        {test} { /* value prints as expected here */}           
        <form>
            <select>
                <option>{test}</option> { /* value prints as [object Object] here */}    
                <option>first last - none@none.com</option>
                <option>first last - none@none.com</option>
                <option>first last - none@none.com</option>
            </select>       
        </form>
    </div>
    )       
}
```

I'm expecting the first option in the drop-down to display as "someFirstName someLastName - someEmail" but it is instead displaying as "[object Object]".
This seems to be specific to forms.

Using JSON.stringify(test) returns what appears to be a string of the entire JSON object. Why does using {test} somewhere in the html deal with that object correctly but not when wrapped in a form option?

Comment: You are putting `<div>`s in your array; inserting a div into JSX like that is no problem, but an `<option>` doesn't support child elements, which means the variable is coerced into a string. The default is `[object Object]`.

Comment: One way to fix this is to map the array to an object containing both the div and the text: https://codesandbox.io/s/2okr9xjj4r

Comment: @ChrisG Is this only populating a single element of an array? When I change the size of array `randomName: 10`, and then `var test = this.state.random[1]`, this breaks.

Comment: `randomName: 10` doesn't change the size, it sets `this.state.randomName` to `10`. a number doesn't have a [1]. I don't really know what your goal is here; are you trying to turn the JSON reply into options? Again: your original code turned a bunch of objects into a bunch of React `<div>` element objects. Inserting those into JSX is fine, inserting them into an `<option>` isn't.

Comment: @ChrisG Whoops, lost my brackets when formatting. Should be `randomName: [10]`. Goal is to set each value from the API to a different option in the drop-down. I'd also like the number of options to change dynamically, so I probably don't want to be setting the size of the array anyway.

Comment: I updated the codesandbox example.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Mind sharing any insight on why explicitly accessing other elements of the array wasn't functioning as I expected in the previous example? I'm also curious as to why using a constructor similar to my original wouldn't work with this code. Even using this.state when initializing seems to break things. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188075/discussion-between-rial-johnson-and-chris-g).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding div in the state on componentDidMount you can do the following:

```
componentDidMount() {       
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
    .then(results => {
        return results.json();
    }).then(data => {
        let randomName = data.results             
        this.setState({ randomName });
    })
}
```

and after then in the render method:

```
renderInfo = () => {
   const {randomName} = this.state 
   return (
        {randomName.map((info) => <option>{info.name.first} {info.name.last} - {info.email}</option>)}
   )
}

render() {             
    return (
    <div>                       
        <form>
            <select>
                {this.renderInfo()}
            </select>       
        </form>
    </div>
    )       
}
```

Hope this may help, thanks

Comment: What would your constructor look like for this? Doesn't compile with my code.

Comment: Still couldn't get this to compile. Either way, I know the issue now and found another solution. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  let Dropdown = mui.react.Dropdown,
  DropdownItem = mui.react.DropdownItem;

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      randomName:''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      }).then(data => {
      let randomName = data.results.map((info => {
        return(
          <DropdownItem key={info.results}>
            {info.name.first} {info.name.last} - {info.email}
          </DropdownItem>
        )
      }))
      this.setState({randomName: randomName});
      console.log("state", this.state.randomName);
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown color="primary" label="Dropdown">
          {this.state.randomName}
        </Dropdown>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
</script>
```